# How can I tell if event system code has been loaded?

Tags: 2013, core-service, event-system

We've written some event handlers to handle editing, building on the example that was started in http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/intro-to-the-event-system

The code worked well in development but didn't appear to work in production.

How can you tell that your event system code has loaded and is running?

Answer (score 12):

The event system code loads when the Tridion Content Manager Service Host service loads, and you can see this in the Windows Event Viewer. As each event handler loads you will see the status showing that the TCM Extension has been initialized.

[image: The event handler loaded successfully]

or

[image: The event handler didn't load]

Comment: But also take into account that it means that the code is loaded by Service Host. For some of the actions, it should also be loaded by publisher, for example

Answer (score 3):

The method I usually use to tell if it loaded, and this applies to any DLL not just Event System, is Process Explorer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx.  It explicitly tells you whether your DLL loaded and by which process, and has an auto-complete search. So you can start typing the name of your DLL and it gives you matching options.